# Proof verification: $\ 2^{n-1} \leq n! $

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing

Prove $\ 2^{n-1} \leq n! $ for all $\ n \in \mathbb{N}. $ I think I completed the proof correctly, but mine is different from the textbook solution. Would the following prove the statement adequately? Thank you.

Let $\ P(n) = 2^{n-1} \leq n! $ for all $\ n \in \mathbb{N} $

$\ P(1) = 2^{0} \leq 1 $ is true.

Let $\ P(m) = 2^{m-1} \leq m! $ for all $\ m \in \mathbb{N} $

Suppose $\ P(m) $ is true.

$\ P(m+1) = 2^{m-1+1} \leq (m+1)! $

$\ = 2^{m} \leq (m+1)! $

$\ = 2^{m-1} \cdot 2 \leq (m+1) \cdot m! $

Because we are assuming $\ 2^{m-1} \leq m! $ is true, the inequality depends on $\ 2 \leq m+1. $

$\ 2 \leq m+1 = 1 \leq m, $ which is true for all $\ m \in \mathbb{N}. $

Thus, $\ P(m) $ holds for $\ P(m+1). $

By induction, $\ P(n) $ holds for all $\ n \in \mathbb{N}. $

Comment: The way you wrote the step $P\left(m+1\right)$ holds assuming $P\left(m\right)$ is true is awkward for me. I feel like you should write in this order to be clearer : 1. We assume $2^{m-1} \leq m!$, 2. Then you show you can deduce $2^{m} \leq \left(m+1\right)!$ and you conclude.

Comment: Welcome to Math S.E.  I would write $2\le m+1\color{red}\iff 1\le m$, etc.; otherwise it looks like $m+1=1$

Comment: Your definition of $P(n)$ is for a single $n$, not all $n$. Also, you don’t need to redefine it for m. Also, using equals for truth values can be confusing.

Comment: Lastly, it’s better to write out how $P(m) $implies $P(m+1)$ in that order.  Think backwards (what you want to what you have), write your proofs forwards (what you have to what you want).

Comment: I know that the question asks for the induction proof, but for your information, the inequality can be rewritten as $$1 \times 2 \times ... \times 2 \leq 1 \times 2 \times 3 \times ... \times n$$ (each product containing $n$ factors), and hence is immediately true without induction.

Comment: Consider using something other than "=" when talking about the definition of a predicate. It may seem pedantic, but you currently have statements like $P(1) = 2^0 \leq 1$, which seems to suggest the nonsensical statement "$P(1) \leq 1$". Better would be to write out "$P(1)$ is defined to be the statement $2^0 \leq 1$".

Comment: The symbol  sometimes means the set of positive integers, and sometimes means the set of nonnegative integers. Which do you mean here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your idea is correct but write it properly. Firstly, $2^{0} \leqslant 1!$. Now, suppose, $2^{n-1} \leqslant n!$ for some $n \geqslant 1$. Then, $2^{n} = 2.2^{n-1} \leqslant (n+1).n! = (n+1)!$. Hence, $2^{n-1} \leqslant n!$ for all $n \geqslant 1$ follows from induction principle.